# Undefined behaviour in C++ while creating arrays and retrieving data from them

Tags: c++, arrays, undefined-behavior

I have undefined behaviour and since I am a beginner in C++, I do not know how to even try to solve this. I was looking at [this link](https://www.nayuki.io/page/undefined-behavior-in-c-and-cplusplus-programs), where it shows possible mistakes. The only guess I have is that I should use malloc maybe?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    int population[100];

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
    {
        population[i] = rand()%(10);
    }

    int firstTournament[2];
    int secondTournament[2];

    int randomNumbers[4] = {};

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    {
        int indexOfIndividual = rand()%(101);
        randomNumbers[i] = indexOfIndividual;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        if(i < 2)
        {    
            firstTournament[i] = population[randomNumbers[i]];
            cout << "first tournament " << firstTournament[i] <<endl;
        }
        else
        {    
            secondTournament[i] = population[randomNumbers[i]];
            cout << "second tournament " << secondTournament[i] <<endl;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
    {
        // This is where the problem starts. It prints gibberish
        cout << "before tournament first  " << firstTournament[i] << endl;
        cout << "before tournament second " << secondTournament[i] << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This is what is printed out:

```
first tournament 4
first tournament 6
second tournament 5
second tournament 3

//This is where the fun begins:
before tournament first 4            // so far correct
before tournament second -1834234234 // ??? 
before tournament first 6            // correct
before tournament second 3266        // the numbers are supposed to be between 0 and 10
```

How do I approach this problem? What am I doing wrong?

I compile it running

```
g++ -std=c++11 -c -I /stuff/include main.cc
```

Comment: Consider what `i` will be when `cout << "second tournament " << secondTournament[i] <<endl;` runs, and how large `secondTournament` is.

Comment: `rand()%(101);` can return `100`, which is out-of-range for indexing `int population[100];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic of your program has a fault. This is where you populate `secondTournament`:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        if(i < 2)
        {    
            firstTournament[i] = population[randomNumbers[i]];
            cout << "first tournament " << firstTournament[i] <<endl;
        }
        else
        {    
            secondTournament[i] = population[randomNumbers[i]];
            cout << "second tournament " << secondTournament[i] <<endl;
        }
    }
```

`secondTournament[0]` is never set. Because when `i` is `0`, `if(i < 2)` is `true` and the `secondTournament[i] = ...` is not executed. Then later, in this block:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
    {
        // This is where the problem starts. It prints gibberish
        cout << "before tournament first  " << firstTournament[i] << endl;
        cout << "before tournament second " << secondTournament[i] << endl;
    }
```

You're printing the `secondTournament[0]` that was not set. Instead, you're setting `secondTournament[2]`and `secondTournament[3]`, both of which are out of bounds. Perhaps what you wanted instead is `secondTournament[i-2] = ...`.

Answer (score 1):

The standard library has a number of functions that do exactly what you are trying to do here.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::mt19937 gen{std::random_device{}()}; // or any other prng   
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dis(0, 9);

    int population[100];
    std::generate(population, population + 100, [&]{ return dis(gen); });

    int firstTournament[2];
    int secondTournament[2];

    std::sample(population, population + 100, firstTournament, 2, gen);
    std::sample(population, population + 100, secondTournament, 2, gen);

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << "before tournament first  " << firstTournament[i] << std::endl;
        std::cout << "before tournament second " << secondTournament[i] << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```